# IBInspectable and floating point values

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is it possible to set floating point value in Attributes Inspector? I have this property in my UIView:

```
@IBInspectable
var scale: CGFloat = 0.90 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
```

As you can see, default value is 0.9 and I would like to change it in Attributes Inspector, but it looks like that:

[image: Attributes Inspector]

And I am only able to set integer values in there. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it's an Xcode limitation. Make sure to open bug report with Apple.

Comment: So you did try to input a decimal and get what...? Both `Float` and `CGFloat` inspectables let me input decimal numbers and work as expected... Also the property should be annotated as `@IBInspectable` instead of `@IBDesignable`...

Comment: Never set floating point value in Inspector.

Comment: @Alladinian `@IBDesignable` in my code was a typo, I copy-pasted the code from XCode without the annotation.
If I try to put decimal point in the field, the field stays selected while I try to select other field in Attributes Inspector. If I change the tab, e.g. to Identity Inspector, the filed gets blank, like in the picture in my question.

Comment: @SebastianOsiński I see... which Xcode version? I can verify that in 6.3.1+ this is working just fine with a `Float` inspectable

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can set it. What worked for me was using a comma when entering the number instead of a period. And as commented by @Alladinian:

> [T]he decimal separator [might just be] locale (region) dependant.

Here it's `0,5`, not `0.5`:
[image: 0,5]

Here it's `0,8`, not `0.8`:
[image: 0,8]

Comment: Oh that makes sense... the decimal separator is locale (region) dependant. This could be the case with the OP also. Nice observation

Comment: Hah, great. I am from a country where a comma is used as a decimal separator and I didn't think about putting comma there. Actually it is quite misleading.

Comment: Yeah it is misleading, as you use a period in the rest of your code.

Comment: The decimal separator used in Storyboard is a comma whereas the code uses a dot... Is this meant as a feature? ._.' Nevertheless, you helped, so have my upvote, sir. :)