# Set increase or decrease step with @IBInspectable

Tags: ios, swift, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I have customized a progress view with `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`. When I clicked the increase button, it alway increase 1 . Can I set it increase anyother number?
[image]

Comment: Do you want it to increase by more (every 2) or less (every 0.5)?

Comment: I am asking which one you are attempting to do: increase by more than 1 (ex. 2, 4, 6, 8) OR increase by less than 1 (ex. 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2)

Comment: Sorry for that! I want it to increase by less

Comment: Okay, is `rate` an integer or a decimal (Float, Double, CGFloat, etc.)

Comment: It's decimal(CGFloat)

Comment: I did find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692868/configuring-ibinspectable-attribute-inspector-controls), except that did not get any answer. I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187890/ibinspectable-and-floating-point-values), but the problem there was with locale. One of the comments of the second question does mention it's an Xcode limitation.